# Prove that any bounded open set has an arbitrarily close closed subset

Tags: real-analysis

Would appreciate collecting proofs on this. I understand most textbooks take this as a given. In full, my question is to prove the following:

> Prove that any bounded open set $O$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (under the usual topology and Lebesgue measure) has an arbitrarily close closed subset $F$.  That is, prove that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a closed $F \subset O$ such $m(O-F) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Please give us a bit more detail in the question. Do you mean in an arbitrary metric space, or is this a measure-space in particular? What do you mean by two sets being "close"?

Comment: Details added. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $U$ be an open set of $X$..given any $\delta >0$ consider $V_\delta$={$ x\in X | d(x,U)\leq \delta$}

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seems true without more hypothesis.

Take a space X with the discrete metric. Take a point $x\in X$, Then every closed set that doesn't contain x is at distance 1 of the open set $\lbrace x\rbrace$.

Comment: But a singleton is also closed, and so is its own "arbitrarily close closed subset" no?

Comment: I've revised my question to provide more detail.

Comment: You should add "with the usual topology", as my counter-exemple work with R^n with the discrete topology